# Minisforum Mini PC - CPU fan starting to become loud

Tags: cpu, fedora, fan, temperature

The unit is Minisforum DeskMini HM80, CPU: AMD Ryzen™ 7 4800U , 8 Cores/16 Threads.

So the CPU fan is becoming quite loud, depending on the temperature. Measured temperature while in BIOS is 61C.

Is this something that is known for Minisforum? More importantly, can I use it like this or I need to take some action (open and clean, apply new thermal paste, maybe change some BIOS settings). It happen suddenly, not gradually. Just received the new unit after motherboard failed on first, so not enough time for dust buildup.

Comment: `take some action` ... why is `replace fan` not in the list?

Comment: Adding it, as a last option. Thanks @jsotola

Comment: Check the temperature sensors when the fans are loud. Check for dust in the airways.

Comment: Replacing the fan really should be the first option as its the correct solution.   Fans are almost consumable items. Even if you can lube it, it will start dying again after not-to-long.

Comment: You can use a system with a dying fan - it soluld juat slow down under load as it cant dissipate the heat (and modern CPUs will throttle to protect themselves). Its not great for the cpu, but it by the time its an issue the cpu will likely be obsolete. It may be frustrating to use though, depending on workload.

Comment: I used a first gen i3 for years in a mini pc as a router with the fan removed. I did underclock it as I did not need the performance, but I am fairly sure the death of the box was not heat related  - and first gen i5's were not energy efficient relative to todays cpu's.

Comment: Thanks @davidgo I edited the OP to show which PC and what CPU. I don't know what replacement fan I should be buying - do I need something niche as this is Mini PC. The another thing is that this is brand new unit, used for under a month, how come it has ''a dying fan''. Will open it tomorrow to check for dust and connections

Comment: Read the reviews for Mini PC's; **many** have loud fans. Do  ot waste time replacing a fan in a new PC. Due to the small size, and your high-end CPU, it needs to move a lot of air to keep from frying. Some suggestions: 1. See if BIOS settings have different fan curves. 2. Mount the PC farther away from your ears. 3. **Careful** removal and reapplication of thermal compound *might* help -- but one often reads of attempts by those with less skill **destroying** the PC.

Comment: I eventually tracked down an image showing the fan for the unit - see 3:02 at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOLWCWHSDEA - You likely need to reach out to the vendor as this is not a typical fan mounted on cpu arrangement.

Comment: Based on last two comments, I think it's best not to remove anything. I've monitored operating temps and while browsing it's between 50-60C, with spikes to 70C territory when you force it with multiple tabs in short period. It quickly reverts to 40-50C. I am less skilled and #3 is very applicable here. @DrMoishePippik Can you clarify on #1 please?

Comment: @morich, look online, e.g., https://cybersided.com/fan-curves/